# libcurl PKG_CONFIG_PATH issue for opkg on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libcurl, opkg

While installing OPKG, following logs are getting generated for "./configure".

```
    checking for CURL... no
    configure: error: Package requirements (libcurl) were not met:

    No package 'libcurl' found

    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CURL_CFLAGS
    and CURL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
    See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have already tried following things:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Please help soon!

Answer (score 2):

After "sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev" restart the R studio its working for both devtools and libcurl installation

Comment: The answer you gave, I have already tried. Refer to question properly.